# What is this CSP report telling me?

Tags: content-security-policy

I'm receiving the following Content Security Policy report. The `font-src` is being violated by `data` I don't understand `data`. Is this something I can ignore as I'm not aware of `data` originating in my code? I'm using Google Analytics, and wonder if it caused by that?

```
{
    "csp-report": {
        "document-uri":
        "effective-directive": "font-src",
        "original-policy": "... ;font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; ...",
        "blocked-uri": "data"
    }
}
```

Comment: If you’re not generating 'data:' URLs anywhere in your own code, then that would seem to indicate some third-party code you’re using/allowing is generating 'data:' URLs. Or you have some browser extension installed that’s doing that. Or else it’s an XSS attack.

Comment: For further information on data urls you can consult https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs